# Ajax deja de funcionar cuando se recarga HTML con formulario

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Tengo una Tienda en mi página que corresponde a un plugin de wordpress.
Para mejorar la experiencia de usuario decidí usar AJAX en la paginación, cosa que el plugin no incluye (si incluye ajax para los botones agregar al carrito).

EL asunto es que cuando cambiaba de página, hacía el render también de la navegación y me estaba recargando todo al hacer el segundo clic en una nueva página. Leí que lo mejor es recargar como HTML eso con lo que no interactúas para que funcione ajax.

El asunto es que cada vez que recargo los productos también recargo el botón agregar al carrito. Entonces, después que cambie de página el primer clic en "Agregar al Carrito" me recarga toda la página otra vez, ya las siguientes interacciones AJAX funciona, mientras no cambie la página.

Es mucho código, pero intentaré colocar el más representativo (el evento onclic de agregar al carrito):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {        
        /*** Handle add to cart action ***/
        $('.eStore-button-form').on('submit', function() {
           //Hace un montón de cosas
}
});


<form method="post" action="" 
      class="eStore-button-form eStore-button-form-24" 
      style="display:inline" 
      onsubmit="return ReadForm1(this, 1);">

<div class="eStore_variation_top"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Comprar" 
     class="eStore_button eStore_add_to_cart_button">

</form>
```

Alguna idea?

*** Actualización ***

```
//Clic en Paginación de Productos
    $('.pagination_page').click(function(){
        href_clic = $(this).attr('href');

        var product_page = $(this).attr("href").match(/product_page=([0-9]+)/)[1];

        //Actualiza la dirección URL. Siempre tiene que ir con un return false después.
        window.history.pushState('obj', 'PageTitle', '/tienda/?product_page=' + product_page);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : vc.ajaxurl,
            type : "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                action : 'vc_eStore_paginacion',
                product_page: product_page,
                nonce: vc.vc_eStore_nonce,
            },
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success : function(respuesta) {

                console.log('ejecución .pagination_page');
                console.log(respuesta);

                $('.eStore-fancy-wrapper').remove();

                var html_productos = $(respuesta.html_product_page).not('.eStore_pagination');
                $(html_productos).insertBefore( ".eStore_pagination" );
            }
        });

        return false;      
    });
```

html_productos es la grilla de productos con su foto y su formulario con botón que se cargan nuevamente en la sección de la página.

Comment: Creo que lo que te puede pasar es que estes usando la clase 'eStore-button-form', y esta clase debe ser para todos los botones de ese tema, tendras que buscar un id o algo que tenga disitinto para que solo afecte a ese boton en concreto por ejemplo, en el form que has puesto tiene algo distintivo 'eStore-button-form-24'

Comment: Hola Jorge, no entiendo la solución que me planteas, disculpa. En la tienda aparecen 4 productos por página, cada uno de esos productos tiene un formulario de este tipo. El código AJAX se ejecuta para todos los botones igual.

Comment: Cual es el codigo que has realizado? no el que viene por defecto, sino el que has puesto ya que para la paginacion no habia ajax.

Comment: Ahí actualicé el código en la pregunta. El tema es con que vuelvo a insertar el HTML que AJAX está "escuchando". La cosa es que no sé como arreglarlo. Antes de hacer la paginación quise cargar nuevamente cada producto individualmente cada vez que se agregaba al carrito, para agregar html informativo en el producto, pero tenía el mismo problema. Pasa cada vez que se redibuja algo que AJAX está escuchando.

Comment: No confundamos conceptos: AJAX simplemente son llamadas HTTP asíncronas hechas por Javascript. Tu llamada AJAX parece recibir como respuesta HTML que insertas en la página. Si es así, todo el nuevo HTML insertado no tendrá ningún *event listener* asociado, con lo que si insertas botones u otros elementos con los que el usuario ha de interaccionar, tendrás que añadir de nuevo los *listeners*.

Comment: genial, como vuelvo a insertar los sin que la página se refresque? En este caso tendría que asociarle un listener a un código que ya existe.

Comment: Depende, si el html que devuelves tiene javascript en linea por ejemplo onsubmit no hace falta event listener

Comment: Me parece que el listener al que hace referencia Pablo es el aue se asigna con la función de ajax. El tema es que la función no está declarada por fuera del mismo elemento al que es asignada dentro del plugin que hace el manejo. Ya veo que no me queda otra que meter mano...

Comment: Prueba primero a meter un alert antes de la declaracion de "href_clic" y luego repetir ese caso donde se recarga la pagina al darle de nuevo al boton de añadir carrito, si te aparece dos alert es lo que te acababa de responder, que el evento click se esta duplicando, y hace que de nuevo se inserte el html

Answer (score 0):

Intenta des asignar el click anterior con `off`, que creo que ese es el problema, arrastra ese evento.

```
   $('.pagination_page').off('click').on('click', function(){
        href_clic = $(this).attr('href');

        var product_page = $(this).attr("href").match(/product_page=([0-9]+)/)[1];

        //Actualiza la dirección URL. Siempre tiene que ir con un return false después.
        window.history.pushState('obj', 'PageTitle', '/tienda/?product_page=' + product_page);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : vc.ajaxurl,
            type : "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                action : 'vc_eStore_paginacion',
                product_page: product_page,
                nonce: vc.vc_eStore_nonce,
            },
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success : function(respuesta) {

                console.log('ejecución .pagination_page');
                console.log(respuesta);

                $('.eStore-fancy-wrapper').remove();

                var html_productos = $(respuesta.html_product_page).not('.eStore_pagination');
                $(html_productos).insertBefore( ".eStore_pagination" );
            }
        });

        return false;      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he solucionado.
para que mi elemento no pierda el listener cuando vuelve a crearse, lo he adjudicado a su contenedor padre que permanece inalterado en la página.

Esto es lo que cambié:

```
$('#product-grid').on('click', '.pagination_page', function (){...
```

En lugar de:

```
$('.pagination_page').click(function(){...
```

Espero que ayude a quienes se encuentren con este mismo problema!
Una vez que entendés AYAX es un placer ver lo que se puede lograr.

Gracias!